# What non-Bayesian classifiers could be used in a naive Bayes model?

Tags: classification, bayesian, naive-bayes

> Bayes' theorem [is used] in the classifier's decision rule, but naive Bayes is not (necessarily) a Bayesian method.

-[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier).

I have applied naive Bayes assumption to LDA, but it has a Bayes classifier as the sole classifier. To what other *non-Bayesian* classifiers or learning models could the naive Bayes assumption be applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line from Wikipedia gives two citations, the latter of which is to

> Hand, D. J.; Yu, K. (2001). "Idiot's Bayes — not so stupid after all?". International Statistical Review. 69 (3): 385–399. [doi:10.2307/1403452](https://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F1403452). ISSN [0306-7734](https://www.worldcat.org/issn/0306-7734).

An excerpt from the end of their section 1:

> Before commencing, however, some clarification of the word 'Bayes' in this context is appropriate. In work on supervised classification methods it has become standard to refer to the $P(i)$ as the class $i$ *prior probability*, because this gives the probability that an object will belong to class $i$ prior to observing any information about the object. Combining the prior with $P(\mathbf x \mid i)$, as shown above, gives the *posterior* probability, after having observed $\mathbf x$. This combination is effected via Bayes theorem, and it is because of this that 'Bayes' is used in the name of these methods. [...] The important point for us is that no notion of subjective probability is introduced: the methods are not [necessarily] 'Bayesian' in the formal statistical sense. [...] In this paper, following almost all the work on the idiot's Bayes method, we adopt a frequentist interpretation.

The Wikipedia claim, I think, is just that naive Bayes need not be interpreted as a Bayesian method based on a subjective prior and so on; it makes perfect sense to think of it as a frequentist method. Similarly, note that the [Bayes classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_classifier) is not an inherently Bayesian concept, but in fact comes up in frequentist analyses quite often; the naive Bayes classifier is simply the Bayes classifier under a certain independence assumption, and so that need not be a Bayesian method either.